# Question about the subspace $E_{n}$ of all vectors in $V$ of even weight.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm given the following example in my textbook:

Consider the vector space $V(n,2)$ of all binary n-tuples, that is, n-tuples of $0$'s and $1$'s. The weight $\mathcal{W}(v)$ of a vector $v \in V(n,2)$ is the number of nonzero coordinates in $v$. For instance, $\mathcal{W}(101010)=3$. Let $E_{n}$ be the set of all vectors in $V$ of even weight. Then $E_{n}$ is a subspace of $V(n,2)$.

To see this, note that

$\mathcal{W}(u+v) = \mathcal{W}(u) + \mathcal{W}(v) - 2\mathcal{W}(u \cap v)$

where $u \cap v$ is the vector in $V(n,2)$ whose $i$th component is the product of the $i$th components of $u$ and $v$, that is,

$(u \cap v)_{i} = u_{i} \cdot v_{i}$

Hence, if $\mathcal{W}$ and $\mathcal{W}(v)$ are both even, so is $\mathcal{W}(u+v)$. Finally, scalar multiplication over $F_{2}$ is trivial and so $E_{n}$ is a subspace of $V(n,2)$, known as the even weight subspace of $V(n,2)$.

Currently, I've tried using the vectors $100111$ and $101000$ as examples. So, when I use that given weight formula, I get

$W(100111 + 101000) = 4 + 2 -2\mathcal{W}(100000)$.

This does indeed give me an even weight of $4$. However, I would like to know if we're even able to do addition of these binary numbers as $100111 + 101000 = 1001111$? When I do this, the weight of this resulting vector is $5$. So, I'm a little confused.

Comment: How is $V(n,2)$ a vector space?  The binary operation isn't addition, right?  Addition doesn't preserve length.  Presumably you just have component addition, which is not the same as ordinary addition in general.

Comment: @lulu: does this mean that in this component addition, $1 + 1 = 0$,  $1 + 0 = 0 + 1 = 1$, and $0 + 0=0$?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  You should confirm that your addition law for weights holds with *this* notion of addition.

Comment: For instance, the sum of $100111$ and $101000$ is $001111$ which has weight $4$, as desired.

Comment: $100111 + 101000 \neq 1001111$. You forgot the leading term. I would caution you against calling these binary numbers since the addition doesn't carry. These are binary words or $n$-tuples.